# How to perform element-wise Boolean operation in a matrix in Armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm working with Armadillo library in C++ and have a matrix-`A`. How do I acquire a `0/1` matrix-`B` where `B_{ij} = 1 iff. A_{ij}>0`?

I really can't afford writing a for loop in my program 'cause it's inside four layers of such.

Thank you!!

Comment: The armadillo library would most likely implement such a function as a loop (hopefully vectorizing at least parts of it). If you cant find that function in Armadillo, I don't think you'll be much worse off if you implement it with loops yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accomplished via Armadillo's [relational operators](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#operators):

```
 mat A = randu<mat>(5,5) - 0.5;

umat B = (A > 0);
```

Note that B has the type "umat" instead of "mat".  The former contains unsigned integer elements.

Comment: Is there a way to access elements from `A` where `B` is 1? I'm used to NumPy in Python where this could be done like this: `A[B] = -1`. However, I'm unable to find its equivalent in Armadillo.

Comment: @AdeelAhmad - see the [.elem()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat) function in Armadillo